# load images dynamically into jquery iviewer

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic-data

Anyone ever loaded images dynamically into jquery iViewer? Currently, it's setup as

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#images").iviewer(
                   {
                   src: "images/voices/big/page01.jpg", 
                   update_on_resize: false,
                   initCallback: function (object)
                   {
                       $("#in").click(function(){ object.zoom(1);}); 
                       $("#out").click(function(){ object.zoom(-1);}); 
                       $("#fit").click(function(){ object.fit();}); 
                       $("#orig").click(function(){ object.toOrig();}); 
                       $("#update").click(function(){ object.update();}); 
                   }
              });
        });
```

so you have to put different instances on the page in order to show more than one image. Currently i have the "scrollable" plugin for thumbnails and i wanted to be able to dynamically load their large images into iViewer plugin. Anyone got any ideas?

Current example here: http://orangepxl.com/yasuko/voices.php only 1 image will work... :(

Answer (score 4):

Please, take the last version of the plugin from the github. Iviewer is now a jQuery UI widget and it has loadImage method, so you can show different images in a single widget.

You could load new image with code like this:

```
jQuery('.iviewer_selector').iviewer('loadImage', 'http://url.to/image.png');
```

See https://github.com/can3p/iviewer for examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can load All of them and, can hide them using jquery, and show them according to the click event for Thumbnails.

Do the iViewer for all of the images and hide them using jquery or just css, 
and when clicking on the thumbnails, show only the corresponding image, and hide rest